# Android dimsiss ImageView on swipe gesture

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, imageview, swipe

In a RelativeLayout I have a TextView and a Button under the TextView and an ImageView covering both of the other objects. As the user opens the activity, the ImageView should cover the other items.
As the user swipes on the image (left or right), it should dismiss so the user can operate the button and read the textfield.

Whith an onClick listener I could dismiss the Image when clicked but I would like an animation, exactly like in a RecicleView when swiping to delete an element.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the desired animation to the onClick event.

1) create(or add if existing) the anim folder inside the res directory and put slide_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

2) Add this code to the onclick action of the image view :

```
// Refer the ImageView like this
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// Load the animation like this
animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.slide_animation);

// Start the animation like this
imageView.startAnimation(animSlide);
```

You can modify the animation specs in the xml so you can get the desired effect.

And then just implement AnimatorListener so you can dismiss the image view at animation end.

```
animSlide.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            //remove image view from the layout
        }
    });
```